# Interpolation in a data set

Tags: interpolation

I have the given dataset

```
dat1 = {{0, 0, 1, 10}, {0, 0, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 1, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3.5}, {1,
0, 1, 0.8}, {1, 0, 2, 0.6}, {1, 1, 1, 0.4}, {1, 1, 2, 0.2}}
```

In the data set 1st element is 'r', second element is 'z', third element is 'E' and the fourth element is value of the function at r, z and E ie. F(r, z, E).

I want to do the interpolation such that I can get the value of F(r, z E) at  any r,z and E.

I have tried the following :

```
    intdat = Flatten[dat1]
    f[z_, r_, e_] := Interpolation[intdat]
```

But I do not get my desired interpolated value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There's an example exactly like this in the documentation for `Interpolation`. If we can see the code you tried, it might be easier for us to point out any issues in the code.

Comment: I have tried this : dat1 = {{0, 0, 1, 10}, {0, 0, 2, 5}, {0, 1, 1, 4}, {0, 1, 2, 3.5}, {1,
    0, 1, 0.8}, {1, 0, 2, 0.6}, {1, 1, 1, 0.4}, {1, 1, 2, 0.2}}, f = Table[dat1],dintp[z_, r_, e_] := Interpolation[Flatten[f]]. But I did not get the result

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for Interpolation suggests the following format for multidimensional interpolations:

```
f = Interpolation[{Most@#, Last@#} & /@ dat1]
f[0.5, 0.5, 1.5] (* 3.0625 *)
```

It is unclear why you are Flattening the dataset.  Evaluating f with three arguments that lie within the provided ranges should work.

Comment: In fact `f = Interpolation[dat1]` does work, but gives a `Interpolation::inhr: "Requested order is too high; order has been reduced to {1,1,1}"` error. So, simply `f = Interpolation[dat1, InterpolationOrder -> {1, 1, 1}]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot bobthechemist. The method is working for me